# Trying to fill.map an array that starts with a specific number in Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to fill an array with a sequence of numbers, but I need to start the array in a specific number and finish in another.

I've tried the following code:

```
pageArray = Array(finalPageValue).fill(1).map((x,i = initialPageValue) => i+1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work better.

```
const initialPageValue = 5
const finalPageValue = 3
const pageArray = Array.from({ length: finalPageValue }).map((x,i) => i+initialPageValue);
```

This part `i = initialPageValue` will not work as you'd expect. That's because default param value is only assigned when the param arrives undefined, which will never be the case for item index. And so the assignment will never kick in.